# Get color space of a texture

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to get the color space (e.g. RGB, CIELUV, etc) from a Texture object in Unity?

```
Texture my_image = (Texture) Resources.Load("cool_picture");

string color_space = SomeFunctionToGetColorSpace(my_image);
```

Comment: Realize you meant the color space not the specific color of a pixel,  in their documentation you can get the color format with my_image.graphicsFormat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unfortunately it's not possible to do unless you use specific algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is 4 years old but I wanted to reply because it is possible to get the colorspace from a texture by using TextureImporter.

```
Texture2D texture;// ...(some texture)
TextureImporter texImport = AssetImporter.GetAtPath(AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(texture))
    as TextureImporter;
ColorSpace textureColorSpace = textureImporter.sRGBTexture ?
    ColorSpace.Linear : ColorSpace.Gamma;
```